# Find if current class contains word, then append new class to those li's - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, each

Having some problems with jQuery methods - perhaps overcomplicating things...

What I need to find is if any of the li elements classes contain the word 'current', then if they do, append the word active to them.

I'm struggling to add the word to the end of the current class. For example:

**Markup:**

```
<div class="menu-navigation-container">
    <ul>
        <li class="current_page_item menu-item-8787"><a href="http://www.cornermag.com/mag/" style="font-size: 1.6rem;"><span>The Magazine</span></a>
        </li>
           <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type"><a href="http://www.cornermag.com/snapped/" style="font-size: 1.6rem;"><span>Snapped</span></a>
           </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var classNames = $('.menu-navigation-container ul li').attr("class").match(/[\w-]*current[\w-]*/g);
    $(classNames).each(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Running `classnames;` up in the console produces just the string - I want it to reference the li elemens that have the word 'current' in their class names, then append the word 'active' at the end.

Can I do this with jQuery's [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)?

Comment: What's wrong with going straight to it with the selector? e.g. `.menu-navigation-container ul li[class*="current"]`

Comment: Why aren't you checking for specific class instead as `current_page_item`???

Comment: Your match finds all strings that have `current` in name. Why now not go through the same elements again and, if they have the given class, add active.

Comment: by `append the word active to them` do you mean to add `active` in class list or rename the class name to `current***active`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu-navigation-container ul li[class*=current]').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Not necessarily the same as the regexp the OP is using. It might be still ok though, depending if OP wants to find `blackcurrent-class`

Comment: It will still match. * mean the class contain that word somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {


    $('.menu-navigation-container ul li').each(function(){

     if ( $(this).is(".current") )
      {
           $(this).addClass("active");
      }

    })




    });
```